# node.js, for-loops, and twitter API

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, twitter

I am trying to only fetch the text of the tweets for a twitter bot I am working on (keep in mind twitter's API docs are worse than Oracles, which I never thought that was possible, anyway). I was using the following link to make my bot https://community.risingstack.com/node-js-twitter-bot-tutorial/

I assume that it is within their randomTweet function where they get the index from.

```
function ranDom (arr) {  
  var index = Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length);
  return arr[index];
};
```

and later in their code they would reference it using

```
Twitter.post('favorites/create', {id: randomTweet.id_str}
```

I am trying to simply access the text using a regular foreach loop (seeing as, as far as I am aware, node.js has no concept of an indexed for loop) as follows:

```
var tweet = data.statuses;



    for(var result in tweet) {
        console.log(result.id_str);
    }
```

However, all I am getting is undefined, and I am not certain as to why since for them it worked fine when they passed in a specific index.

Comment: upon further inspection, apparently the result was actually returning the index number itself...that is soo strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the index use `Object.keys(tweet).indexOf(result)`